# Run-away functions

Tags: real-analysis, ds.dynamical-systems, discrete-dynamical-systems, topological-dynamics

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function.  We say that f has the run-away property if for every compact subset  $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ there is some positive integer N such that for every $n \geq N$
$$
f^n(K) \cap K = \emptyset.
$$

Some toy examples include:

1. $f(x)=x+b$ for non-zero b.
2. $f(x)=\exp(x)$.

Some non-examples are:

1. $f(x)=x^2 - b$ for positive b *(since iterates of any compact neighborhood of the root of $x^2 -x -b$ always contain that fixed point).*
2. $f(x)=\sin(x)$ *(since the compact $[-1,1]$ is never escaped)*.

In general is there a known *sufficient* condition on f for it to be run-away?

**Thoughts:**

It seems that unbounded range (not necessarily surjective), and no periodic points are necessary...

Comment: Why is monotone necessary? Doesn't $f(x)=|x|+1$ work?

Comment: No fixed points (i.e. either $f(x) > x$ for all $x$ or $f(x) < x$ for all $x$) should be necessary and sufficient.

Comment: @SamHopkins I guess you're thinking that since $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ is convergent we will travel only a finite distance from the initial point. But it is actually wrong! Because $\frac{1}{|x_n|^2}$ is not $\frac{1}{n^2}$, but something much smaller this would give us divergence.

Comment: @AlekseiKulikov: yes, I see, you are right!

Comment: If we relax the continuity assumption then I think $|f(x)|>x$ works (since then we can take something like $f(x)= -|x|-1$ on intervals $[n,n+1]$ with n even and $f(x)= |x| +1$ otherwise?

Comment: You seem to refer to $x = \sqrt b$ as a fixed point of $f(x) = x^2 - b$, but it isn't.

Comment: Ah you're right!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted in the question's comments by [Aleksei Kulikov](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/364244/run-away-functions#comment919269_364244), a necessary and sufficient condition is given by the following:

**Theorem 1**

A real continuous function f is a runaway function iff $f(x)=x$ has no solution for $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

To prove this we need the following lemma:

**Lemma**

Let $f$ be continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)>x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Then for any real values $x$ and $u$ with $x<u$ $$\exists_{N \in \mathbb{N}} \mid \forall_{n\geq N}  f^{(n)}(x) > u,$$ and $N$ can be chosen to be less than $1+(u-x)/G$ where $G=\min_{s \in [x,u]} (f(s)-s)$.

**Proof**

Since $g(x)=f(x)-x$ is continuous,  by the [extreme value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem) it attains its bounds on $[x,u]$ and in particular there exists $\theta \in [x,u]$ s.t. $g(\theta)\leq g(t)$ for all $t \in [x,u]$. Since $f(x)>x$ for all $x$, $g(\theta)>0$. Hence there exists real $G=g(\theta)>0$ s.t. $f(s)\geq s+G$, for all $s \in [x,u].$

We know that $f(x)\geq x+G$. If $f(x)>u$ we are done so assume that $f(x)\in [x,u]$. Then by the above we have $f^{(2)}(x)=f(f(x))\geq f(x)+G\geq x+2G$. Clearly by induction we can prove $$\forall_{n \in \mathbb{N}}f^{(n)}(x)\leq u \implies \forall_{n \in \mathbb{N}}f^{(n)}(x)\geq x+nG.$$

However if we choose $n>(u-x)/G$ then $f^{(n)}(x)\geq x+nG > x+(u-x)=u$.

This is a contradiction. Hence there must exist an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $f^{(N)}(x)>u$ and then clearly since $f(t)>t$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$,  $f^{(n)}(x)>f^{(n-1)}(x)>\dotsb>f^{(N)}(x)>u$  for all $n\geq N$. Clearly $N$ can be chosen to not exceed $1+(u-x)/G$ and we are done.  $\blacksquare$

**Proof of Theorem 1**

If $f(x)=x$ for some $x\in \mathbb{R}$ then the non-empty compact set $X=\{x\}$ is fixed by $f$ and hence $f^{(n)}(X)\cap X = X \cap X = X\neq \emptyset$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.  Thus $f$ is not a runaway function.

If $f(x)\neq x$ for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$  then since $f$ is continuous either $f(x)>x$ or $f(x)<x$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. This is because if the continuous function $g(x)=f(x)-x$ takes both strictly positive and strictly negative values then by the intermediate value theorem it has a real root $a$ which satisfies $f(a)=a$.

Assume wlog $f(x)>x$ for all $x$ (for the other case take continuous $f_1(x)=-f(-x)>x$).

Take any interval $[a,b]$. Lemma 1 then says that for any $x\in[a,b]$ we can find $h(x) \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ s.t. $\forall_{n\geq h(x)}  f^{(n)}(x) > b$ and $h(x)$ can be chosen to not exceed $1+(b-x)/G$ where $G=\min_{s \in [a,b]} (f(s)-s)$.

However $1+(b-x)/G<1+(b-a)/G$ and $G'=\min_{s \in [a,b]} (f(s)-s)\leq G = \min_{s \in [x,b]} (f(s)-s)$, and since $f(x)-x$ is continuous, by the [extreme value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem), the minimum is attained at some point $\mu \in [a,b]$. Thus $G'=f(\mu)-\mu>0$.

Hence $h(x)$ can be chosen not to exceed $h=1+(b-a)/G'$ where $G'=\min_{s \in [a,b]} (f(s)-s)>0$. Thus for any $x\in[a,b]$ we can find $h \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ s.t. $\forall_{n\geq h}  f^{(n)}(x) > b$. Clearly this implies that $\forall_{n\geq h}  f^{(n)}([a,b]) \cap [a,b] = \emptyset$.

Now any compact set $S$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is bounded hence we can find a closed interval $[a,b]$ which contains it. By the above we can find $h \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ s.t. $\forall_{n\geq h} f^{(n)}([a,b]) \cap [a,b] = \emptyset $ which implies that $$\forall_{n\geq h}( f^{(n)}(S)\cap S \subset f^{(n)}([a,b]) \cap [a,b] = \emptyset ).$$

Hence we have proved that $f$ is a runaway function if there does not exist $x\in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f(x)=x$. This, combined with the first implication, proves the result. $\blacksquare$

Comment: this seems like it should be a known fact...do you have a reference by chance?

Comment: @AIM_BLB Sorry I did search but didn't find anything relevant so I just worked this out from scratch. I am reasonably sure there must be something more general you can deduce this from if you look hard enough.

Comment: You assume that WLOG $f(x)>0$ but the function $x \mapsto x + 1$ is runnaway, continuous, and fails this.... Why is this not a problem?

Comment: Thanks for your comment - I meant to say wlog $g(x)>0$ so $f(x)>x$. I've corrected this now.

Comment: That's what I assumed you meant but I just wanted to be sure :)

Comment: In the statement of your lemma, you take $G$ to be the minimum of $f(s) - s$ for $s \in [x, u]$; but, in the proof, you require $G$ to be strictly *smaller* than the minimum.  (This doesn't much matter, since it only makes the upper bound $1 + (u - x)/G$ bigger, but I found the notational mismatch confusing.)

Comment: @LSpice Thank you for your comment which I definitely agree with, I will fix it now.